# Some questions on random sum of i.i.d random variables

Tags: stochastic-processes

Recently, I have started studying stochastic processes based on [Ross](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471120626). However, at the start of the book, I have struggled with some difficulties. Actually, I can't understand the following example: Indeed, I can't understand why in the highlighted formula he argues that the sum in $\sum$ is independent of $N$? intuitively they are dependent.

[image]

Comment: The value of $N$ does not affect the individual $X_i$, due to independence.  So while $\exp\left\{t \sum\limits_1^N X_i\right\}$ does depend on $N$, for any given $n$ you have   $\exp\left\{t \sum\limits_1^n X_i\right\}$ is independent of $N$

Comment: Thanks a lot, why $E[exp(t\sum_{i}^{N}X_i)|N=n]=E[exp(t\sum_{i}^{n}X_i)|N=n]$?

Comment: Because you are conditioning on $N=n$

Comment: OMG, that's right, thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$N$ is independent of the entire sequence $(X_1,X_2,...)$ so it is independent of $(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$. This implies that it is independent of $ f(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ for any measurable function $f$ on $\mathbb R^{n}$. Take $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=e^{ t\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} x_i}$. This function is continuous, hence measurable.

Comment: thanks a lot, why $E[exp(t\sum_{i}^{N}X_i)|N=n]=E[exp(t\sum_{i}^{n}X_i)|N=n]$?

Comment: @OptimizeLife $E(Y|A)=\frac 1 {P(A)} EYI_A$. Take $A=N, Y=e^{t\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}X_i} $ and note that $e^{t\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}X_i} I_A$ is same as $e^{t\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}X_i} I_A$.

Comment: Can you suggest to me a good book in order to learn these kinds of perquisites?

Comment: K L Chung's A Course in Probability Theory is a good book. @OptimizeLife

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response